# 'mapfile' command equivalent for bash 3.2.57

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, macos

I have MacOS *El Capitan* - about bash it is:

```
bash --version
... version: 3.2.57(1)-release...
...
```

I did realise the `mapfile` command is not available

Through the following post:

- [Bash and IFS: string split to an array with specific separator based on a complete word-term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067745/bash-and-ifs-string-split-to-an-array-with-specific-separator-based-on-a-comple)

The following solution works fine:

```bsh
$ string='[Git status]-fn:-functionGitStatus'
$ mapfile -t array <<< "${string//-fn:-/$'\n'}"
$ echo "${array[@]}"
[Git status] functionGitStatus
$ echo "size: '${#array[@]}'"
2
$ for e in "${array[@]}"; do echo "'$e'"; done
'[Git status]'
'functionGitStatus'
```

With what other command available on bash 3.2.57 I can accomplish the same approach?